# Input type number strange behaviour

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-core, input, numbers

I'm building a fruit and vegetables e-commerce app. I have made a system for users to add items to cart by entering values in an `<input type="number">` field, within a form.

The problem I'm having is that when I enter "1.2" for example, my server receives the value "12". But when I enter the value "1", my server just receives the value "1". This really bugs me. Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Some data for context: my backend is build in Asp.Net Core 3.x. The backend endpoint looks like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateShoppingCart(int productId, float amount)
{   
    Console.WriteLine(amount);
    var selectedProduct = _productRepository.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == productId);
    float productCount = 0;
    if(selectedProduct != null)
    {   
        productCount = _shoppingCart.UpdateCart(selectedProduct, realAmount);
    }
    return Redirect(Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString());
}
```

The html part looks like this

```
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="float-left">
        <p>Cantidad:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="float-right">
        <form method="post" class="form-inline" asp-controller="ShoppingCart" asp-action="UpdateShoppingCart">
            <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="@Model.Product.Id"/>
            <input name="amount" type="number" class="form-control h-auto input-add-to-cart" data-id="@Model.Product.Id" min=0 step="0.1" value="@(Model.ShoppingCartItem != null ? (Model.ShoppingCartItem.Amount).ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")) : (0).ToString())"/>
            <button type="submit" id="update-button-@Model.Product.Id" disabled class="ml-1 btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning"><i class="material-icons material-icons-actual-font" disabled>shopping_cart</i>Actualizar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

UPDATE:

The code for the ShoppingCartItem model is the following:

```cs
public class ShoppingCartItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public float Amount { get; set; }
    public string ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
}
```

SECOND UPDATE:

Could it be that i'm setting a culture in the thread that uses the comma as a dot?

In the `Configure` method of `Startup`, i'm setting

```cs
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("es-CL");
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "$";

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

Comment: Can you check the type of Model.ShoppingCartItem.Amount property

Comment: @ScareCrow of course, I'll update the post with the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that was it.

The problem was that my Browser was setting the decimal separator as a dot (for example, `4.7`) and my backend was expecting a comma (for example, `4,7`) so that confused my application.

The culprit was what was posted on my second update, that was

```cs
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("es-CL");

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```